# Laravel 5.4 wrong login always gets 'These credentials do not match our records'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have created a login with a verification email which works fine on Laravel 5.4.

When I login with the correct 'email', 'password' and 'activated' (this means the user approved his email), I can login successfully.
My problem is that when I try to login with an inactivated user, a wrong email or login, I will always get the same error.

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object ( [bags:protected] => Array ( [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object ( [messages:protected] => Array ( [email] => Array ( [0] => These credentials do not match our records. ) ) [format:protected] => :message
```

How can I get more meaningful with wrong login message?

P.S.

I didn't provide the User Scheme because with the correct data, the login is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `LoginController` uses `AuthenticateUsers` trait, you can override for example `sendFailedLoginResponse` just to verify the exact reason.

Instead of:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

you can write something like this in your `LoginController`:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->input('email'))->first();

    if ($user && !$user->activated) {
        $errorMessage = 'You need to activate your account first'; // you can use trans here too
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = trans('auth.failed');
    }

    $errors = [$this->username() => $errorMessage];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Above is probably the easiest way (but some extra query will be run into database).

Comment: Thanks a lot . That's exactly what I needed

Comment: btw you are missing a closed parenthesise after ('email)
`$user = User::where($this->username(), $request->input('email'))->first();`